# Display 3D pdf in ASP.Net Core Page

Tags: asp.net-core, pdf, 3d-model

I have a pdf file which contains a navigable 3D model when I try to open it using Adobe Reader it asks me to trust this document to view and navigate the 3D model.

I would like to display this PDF in an ASP.NET Core (MVC) project, I asked around and found how to display a PDF using either  or  tags but those work for normal PDF not 3D one when I tried to ask ChatGPT its solution didn't work and the PDF won't show at all; it suggested to use 3rd party library PDF.JS but it didn't work.

I am relatively new to ASP.NET and would like some help on how to display a PDF that contains 3D models and allow access (Trust) this document to show its content in the page ?

I tried a code generated from chatGPT like this:

```
<div id="pdfContainer" style="border:solid 1px red"></div>

<script src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
<script>

    // PDF.js code to render the PDF
    var pdfUrl = '~/3D.pdf';
    var container = document.getElementById('pdfContainer');

    // Set the worker source URL (required by PDF.js)
    PDFJS.workerSrc = 'https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

    // Load and render the PDF
    PDFJS.getDocument(pdfUrl).then(function (pdf) {
        pdf.getPage(1).then(function (page) {
            var scaleFactor = 1.5;

            var vwPort = page.getViewport({ scale: scaleFactor });

            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            canvas.height = vwPort.height;
            canvas.width = vwPort.width;
            container.appendChild(canvas);

            var renderContext = {
                canvasContext: context,
                viewport: vwPort
            };

            page.render(renderContext);
        });
    });
</script>
```

And it didn't show the PDF at all.